# Am I crazy, or is "underappreciated" one word?

Tags: orthography

I've always written "underappreciated" as one word, but as I'm typing this, my browser spell-check is trying to correct it to "under appreciated" (with the second suggestion being "under-appreciated" with a hyphen). My phone's auto-correct also changes it to "under appreciated" (no hyphen). Every dictionary I've looked it up in has it as one word. Am I going crazy or is it an error in the spell-checker? Both my computer and phone are Apple products so I assume they use the same dictionary for spell-check.

Comment: Go with the [dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/underappreciate) over auto-correct.

Comment: I've noticed this sort of thing a lot more in the last year. It happens with 'un' words like unreinforced https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unreinforced too.

Comment: You're crazy, since it's insanity to expect a spell checker to be right 100% of the time.

Comment: Why would you trust a spellchecker over trustworthy dictionaries?

Comment: Auto-correct is risky,  A spellchecker is good for typos, but its vocabulary is limited.

Comment: I honestly don't understand why mods wouldn't close such a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merriam-Webster.com says that you are not crazy.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underappreciated

But your question....

Comment: I know my question is silly. I just felt like I was going crazy because I couldn't find any bug reports regarding the misspelling in the autocorrect dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Go with the dictionary. Spell-check has limited accuracy.